# Capturing match point 'in' list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Sometimes I encounter situations where I would like to capture the match point within
a comprehension, for example, in this segment:

```
for child1 in node1.getChildren():
    if child1.getData() in [child2.getData() for child2 in node2.getChildren()]:
        # somehow I want the list comprehension to side effect and capture child2 match point
        doNodes(child1, child2)
        # Or if we capture an index:
        doNodes(child1, node2.getChild(idx)
    else:
        doOther()
```

Is there a way to do this (either capture child2 or its index) without opening another loop for node2 - even using something other than compresensions.

In other words: we are just looking to shortcut the inner loop to avoid longer code and using flags to test the loop match.

Note: probably similar to this one: [Finding the index of elements based on a condition using python list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270321/finding-the-index-of-elements-based-on-a-condition-using-python-list-comprehensi)

Comment: why do you not want to open another loop? you already got two loops.

Comment: There is no “match point within a comprehension”. A list comprehension returns a list. Do you want to get the first `child2` with the same data as the `child1`? Can there be more than one?

Comment: @minitech: we know that, but I'm just asking about a possible side effect or some other technique to avoid an inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need:

```
for child1 in node1.getChildren():
    for child2_idx, child2 in enumerate(node2.getChildren()):
        if child1.getData() == child2.getData():
            doNodes(child1, child2_idx, child2)
            break
    else:
        doOther()
```

The `else` part will be executed when there is no `break` from the `for` loop. E.g. when the matching `child2` is not found.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like -

```
for child1 in node1.getChildren():
    c1data, c2index = next(((child2.getData(),i) for i, child2 in enumerate(node2.getChildren()) if child2.getData() == child1.getData()) , (None,None))
    if c1data:
        # get child2 using the index above - c2index
        doNodes(child1, child2)
```

This returns the first index where they match.

Explanation -

1. We create a generator function that returns the index and data for child2, where `child2.getData() == child1.getData()` condition is met.
2. Then we pass that generator function into `next()` method and specify that if the generator does not return a next value (that is it throws StopIteration) , we should return `(None, None)` instead.
3. Then We check whether the c1data is `None` or not. If its `None` that means no values matched, otherwise a value matched and the index of the match is in the variable `c2index`

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [6,7,4,8,9]
>>> cd,cidx = next(((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(l2) if x == l1[3]), (None,None))
>>> cd
4
>>> cidx
2
>>> cd,cidx = next(((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(l2) if x == l1[4]), (None,None))
>>> print(cd)
None
>>> print(cidx)
None
```