# Find the minimum and maximum indices of a list given a condition

Tags: python, list, numpy, indices

I have a list, let's say:

```
list_A = [0,0,0,1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0,0,0]
```

I would like to find the minimum and maximum indices of this list where `list_A > 0`, i.e. in the above example, it would be 3 and 7.

For other lists, which increase monotonically, I have been using `np.searchsorted`, like `np.searchsorted(list,[0.5,1.0])` to find the indices wherein the list is `between 0.5 and 1.0` respectively.

But this case is quite different and the `np.searchsorted` doesn't work here, or maybe it does in a way which I don't know !

Comment: This is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270321/finding-the-index-of-elements-based-on-a-condition-using-python-list-comprehensi
(don't know how to mark it as so)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter the zipped list with its indixes and take the min and the max:

```
>>> list_A = [0,0,0,1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0,0,0]
>>> filtered_lst = [(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(list_A) if y > 0]
>>> max(filtered_lst)
(7, 1.0)
>>> min(filtered_lst)
(3, 1.0)
```

If you just need the index, unpack the returned value:

```
>>> maX,_ =  max(filtered_lst)
>>> maX
7
```

Comment: Your solution is really simply. But what I need is just the index, not the value (i.e. 1.0). `filtered_list[0]` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `next()`:

```
list_A = [0,0,0,1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0,0,0]

print(next(idx for idx, item in enumerate(list_A) if item>0))
print(next(len(list_A)-1-idx for idx, item in enumerate(list_A[::-1]) if item>0))
```

**Output**

```
3
7
```

Using `next()` to find the first item in the list `> 0` is an elegant solution.

To find the **last** item in the list `> 0` is trickier with this method. I use `next()` to iterate over and find the **first** item `> 0` in the reversed list using `list_A[::-1]`. I then convert the index generated to the correct index by subtracting it from `len(list)-1`, using `len(list)-1-idx` .

Comment: could you elucidate a bit further on what the second step is doing?

Comment: Yes! But I find the solution of Daniel more user-friendly to read. So I have accepted that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function to return indices of all `elements > 0`

```
In [116]: list_A = [0,0,0,1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0,0,0]

In [117]: arr = np.array(list_A)

In [118]: indx = np.where(arr > 0)[0]

In [119]: mini = indx[0]

In [120]: mini
Out[120]: 3

In [121]: maxi = indx[-1]

In [122]: maxi
Out[122]: 7
```