# How can I get an index of an outer list element in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
mylist = [[0, [0]], [2, [1]], [3, [4]], [4, [1, 4]]]
```

I want to get the index of the element of the outer list given the element.

I have tried this, but this only fetches me the outer elements of the list.

```
get_index = [outer for outer, inner in mylist]
```

I want something like this:

```
Input: 2
Output: 1

Input: 4
Output: 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of elements based on a condition using python list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270321/finding-the-index-of-elements-based-on-a-condition-using-python-list-comprehensi)

Comment: The condition here being `element[0] == target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension with `enumerate` to easily look up the index from the first values:

```
d = {i[0]:ix for ix, i in enumerate(mylist)}
# {0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}
```

---

```
d[2]
# 1

d[4]
# 3
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it!

Answer (score 0):

A function matching the desired input/output behavior:

```
def loc( x, ml ):
    return [a for a,b in ml].index(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a function to which you pass an Input and get the corresponding index as output

```
def get_index(inp):
    idx = [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if inp==j[0]]
    return idx[0]

inp = 2
get_index(inp)
# 1

inp = 4
get_index(inp)
# 3
```