# How to remove an element when I traverse a list

Tags: python

I read this in how to remove element as I traverse a list:
[Remove elements as you traverse a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352885/remove-elements-as-you-traverse-a-list-in-python)

Use this as an example:

```
>>> colors=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
>>> filter(lambda color: color != 'green', colors)
['red', 'blue', 'purple']
```

But how can I do that if i want to remove the element if it is part of a string?
i.e I want to filter 'green' if I input just 'een' (just part of 'green' string element in colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension is a shorter version of this loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in colors:
   if 'een' not in i:
       new_list.append(i)
```

Here is the list comprehension equivalent:

```
new_list = [i for i in colors if 'een' not in i]
```

You can also use the filter example, like this:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: 'een' not in x, colors)
['red', 'blue', 'purple']
```

Keep in mind this won't change the original `colors` list, it will just return a new list with only the items that match your filter.  You can *remove* the items that match which will modify the original list, however you need to start from the end to avoid problems with consecutive matches:

```
for i in colors[::-1]: # Traverse the list backward to avoid skipping the next entry.
    if 'een' in i:
       colors.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of using `filter()`:

```
>>> colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
>>> [color for color in colors if 'een' not in color]
['red', 'blue', 'purple']
```

Or, if you want to continue using `filter()`:

```
>>> filter(lambda color: 'een' not in color, colors)
['red', 'blue', 'purple']
```

Comment: No need for print on the interactive prompt.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Nah, but I like adding it :). Eh, I might as well remove it

Comment: without print, `repr(x)` gets printed in the interactive prompt. With print, `str(x)` is printed. So it depends what you want to see. (Although it doesn't matter for lists of strings.)

Comment: @ChrisBarker Yea, not necessary for lists (at least list of strings):p